# Magento - Get product name for all languages

Tags: magento, export, product

When reading all magento products for a export extension I've encountered a problem:
when trying to get the name of a product by using getName() on the loaded model you only get the active language name or if that is not set the default name of the product. But I need to get all product names for default, english, german, french, etc.
Does anyone have a solution for this problem or an idea how to solve it?

```
$model      = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$collection = $model->getCollection();
foreach ($collection as $product) {
   $id   = $product->getId();
   $model->load($id);
   $name = $model->getName(); // gives you only the active language name / default name
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you also want the `default` store, I'm only aware of one working way:

```
$aStoreHash = Mage::getModel('core/store')
    ->getCollection()
    ->setLoadDefault(true)
    ->toOptionHash();

$aName = array();

foreach ($aStoreHash as $iStoreId => $sStoreName) {
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($iStoreId);
    $oCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        // Uncomment next line for testing if you have thousands of products
        // ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('from' => 1, 'to' => 5))
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name');
    foreach ($oCollection as $oProduct) {
        $aName[$oProduct->getId()][$iStoreId] = $oProduct->getName();
    }
}
var_dump($aName);
```

If you don't need the `default` store, you could drop `Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($iStoreId);` and use `->addStoreFilter($iStoreId)` on the collection instead.